# Reasons to use open circuit stub over a short circuit stub

Tags: high-frequency, microwave

I am having trouble with this question which states: suggest two reasons why the use of an open circuit stub might be preferable to a short circuit stub in microwave circuit design (microstrip)

Could someone please help

Comment: Waveguide or printed circuit? If it's printed circuit, what type of lines (microstrip, stripline, etc)?

Comment: I am unsure as the question does not state whether its printed circuit or waveguide.
I  believe it is a **microstrip** transmission line

Comment: If this is a homework (or homework-like) question you should also say what you have already considered as answers and why you think they might not be right (or not complete).

Comment: Sounds like homework to me.  matty_p07 - start by listing the differences between an open circuit and a short circuit (and for completeness one that's terminated in the impedance of the transmission line).  See what you can conclude from that.  Whether it's microstrip or stripline really doesn't matter for this exercise.

Comment: There is one very obvious reason if using a microstrip transmission line (that can't be applied to waveguides).

Comment: If you have DC on the circuit (typically via a bias-T), then an shorted stub will have undesirable DC characteristics...